# How to use cryptocompare API with Xamarin Forms

Tags: json, rest, xamarin.forms, deserialization, json-deserialization

Hi I am trying to make a Xamarin app which shows different cryptocurrency rates. I decided to use the CryptoCompare API for this. I have the Data Model as such:

```
public class Coin
{
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    public string USD { get; set; }

}
```

And this is how I am calling the API

```
public class DataService
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public DataService()
    {

    }
    public async Task<List<Coin>> GetCoinsAsync()
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XRP&tsyms=USD,BTC");

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var Coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(content);
            return Coins; 
    }
}
```

Through debugging, I have realized that while the content variable contains the API data (`{"NZD":3.89,"BTC":0.0001567}`) the Coins variable is staying null.
The problem is in this line

`var Coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(content);`

I get an error saying

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current 
JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Crypto.Models.Coin]' because the type 
requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or 
change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a 
primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) 
that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be 
added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'USD', line 1, position 7.
```

I realize its telling me how to fix it but Im not sure how to fix it. Any help please? Thanks

Comment: FYI there is a C# library out there that already implements this :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis do you mean this? https://github.com/joancaron/cryptocompare-api
I did try use this initially, but due to the lack of documentation, I couldn't figure it out :/

Comment: The general API documentation is [here](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/). The library follows these calls so you should be able to figure it out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check what response you get from the service and correct your model.**

Why do you expect a collection when a single item is retuned?

Next time when you have to deal with JSON and you want to quickly generate the C# models use services like https://app.quicktype.io. Now just give a logical names to your classes.

```
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var data = Welcome.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("USD")]
        public double Usd { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("BTC")]
        public double Btc { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Welcome self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my model as you have shown above. Could you please explain how I can now use this? i.e. Get the value to show on the app. I'm still getting the same error on the line 
`var Coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coin>>(content);`
sorry if this is a silly question, i'm new to this and trying to learn

Comment: var data = Welcome.FromJson(jsonString);